# Iterate through nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Im trying to create a function `increase_by_one` which takes in a dictionary and modifies the dictionary by increasing all values in it by 1. The function should remain all keys unchanged and finally return the modified dictionary. If the dictionary is empty, return it without changing. (Dictionaries can be nested)

e.g

```
increase_by_one({'1':2.7, '11':16, '111':{'a':5, 't':8}})
```

would give

```
{'1': 3.7, '11': 17, '111': {'a': 6, 't': 9}}
```

Im not sure how to do it for multiple(and unknown of number) nested dicitionaries. Thank you. Would prefer the code to be as simple as possible

Comment: You may want to look into recursion.

Comment: And when you do that make sure your dict is not circular :)

Comment: Please paste your current code, so someone can help with where you are stuck rather than coding for you

Comment: What can the values be? Anything or just either floats or dicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values are either a number or a dictionary, you could consider:

```
def increase_by_one(d):
  for key in d:
    if type(d[key])==dict:
      d[key] = increase_by_one(d[key])
    else:
      d[key] += 1
  return d
```

For you input:

```
print(increase_by_one({'1':2.7, '11':16, '111':{'a':5, 't':8}}))
```

I got:

```
{'1': 3.7, '11': 17, '111': {'a': 6, 't': 9}}
```

Comment: But of course @languitar's solution is more elegant

Comment: Other kinds of dictionaries won't work with this (e. g. `SortedDict`).

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple way to solve the problem using recursion and dict comprehension:

```
def increase_by_one(d):
    try:
        return d + 1
    except:
        return {k: increase_by_one(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

In case there are values contained in the dict apart from numbers which can be added or other dictionaries, further type checking might be necessary.

Comment: Builds a new dictionary, doesn't change the original one as wanted by OP.

Comment: @Alfe I am not sure. There is "return the modified dictionary" in the question, which I do.

Comment: No, you return a new dictionary, not the modified one.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think your answer is the best solution to the real problem because this functional approach typically is less error-prone, never leaves half-changed values after an exception etc.  It just isn't hat the OP asked for.

Comment: Let's see what the OP accepts. Might just be formulated imprecisely.

Answer (score 1):

```
def increase_by_one(d):
  for key in d:
    try:
      d[key] += 1
    except:  # cannot increase, so it's not a number
      increase_by_one(d[key])
  return d  # only necessary because of spec
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def increase_by_one(dictio):
    for d in dictio:
        if isinstance(dictio[d], int) or isinstance(dictio[d], float):
            dictio[d] += 1
        else:
            increase_by_one(dictio[d])
    return dictio

increase_by_one({'1':2.7, '11':16, '111':{'a':5, 't':8}})
```

Using recurrence

Comment: Python knows more nuymber types than just `int` and `float` (e. g. `complex` and other stuff imported from `numpy` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In-place modification of dict:

```
def increase_by_one(my_dict):
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if any(isinstance(v, x) for x in (float, int)):
            my_dict.update({k: v + 1})
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            my_dict.update({k: increase_by_one(v)})
    return my_dict

v = {'1': 2.7, '11': 16, '111': {'a': 5, 't': 8}}
print(increase_by_one(v))  # prints: {'111': {'a': 6, 't': 9}, '1': 3.7, '11': 17}
```